# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' in keras_squeezenet

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to import keras_squeezenet into my project, but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/belog/drone_sees/train_model.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras_squeezenet import SqueezeNet
  File "C:\Users\belog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_squeezenet\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras_squeezenet.squeezenet import SqueezeNet
  File "C:\Users\belog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_squeezenet\squeezenet.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\belog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "C:\Users\belog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 19, in <module>
    from keras import backend
  File "C:\Users\belog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager.context import get_config
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config'
```

Here is the import code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras_squeezenet import SqueezeNet
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Convolution2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
```

How to fix this error? (I'm using keras-squeezenet==0.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try upgrading tensorflow:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```